# pgfplots: How to remove all axis lines of polaraxis?

Tags: pgfplots, polar

I need to draw a polar coordinate system **without border lines**.
Adding `axis lines=none` (without star) to pgfplot's polaraxis argument list blanks out the coordinate system completely (including grid lines, tick lines, etc).
Adding **`axis lines*=none`** (with star) as in the following MWE removes the black axis line at the inner edge and the left edge of the sector. That's already half the job -- **how can I remove the outer edge and the right edge?**  (cf. screenshot below)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{polaraxis}[%
                        xmin=-5,%
                        xmax=95,%
                        ymin=10,%
                        ymax=30,%
                        axis lines*=none,%
                        ]
        \end{polaraxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result of MWE with only the outer and right axis line remaining]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `axis line style = {draw=white,line width=0.0001pt},` to the options (bit of a hack though). You can even omit `draw=white` and simply put `axis line style = {line width=0.0001pt},`. Line is there but invisible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{polaraxis}[%
                        xmin=-5,%
                        xmax=95,%
                        ymin=10,%
                        ymax=30,%
                        axis lines*=none,%
                        axis line style = {draw=white,line width=0.0001pt},
                        ]
        \end{polaraxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It turns out that `axis line style = {transparent}` also works :-).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that for a decent version of `pgfplot` (I'm running on 3.1.1) it is possible to add `axis line style = {draw=none}` to the `polaraxis` options. I prefer not to draw the lines rather than make them invisible.

Knowing that, the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}
    [%
        axis line style = {draw=none},%
        xmin = -5,%
        xmax = 95,%
        ymin = 10,%
        ymax = 30,%
    ]
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]